# How do I deploy a theme to a SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, themes

I've got a SharePoint 2010 feature that I'm upgrading to SharePoint 2013.  In 2010, I'm creating a virtual directory in IIS for a theme that my site uses.  The theme consists of a .css and a .skin file in an App_Themes virtual directory on the site's root.  I create the virtual directory through a feature activation routine.

In 2013, I'd like to eliminate the creation of virtual directories.  Ideally, I'd like SharePoint to host what was in my App_Themes virtual directory.  Is there a way to do that?  In 2010, creating the App_Themes virtual folder enabled me to use this theme in the web.config pages element like this:

```
<pages enableSessionState="false" enableViewState="true" **theme="DefaultTheme"**  enableViewStateMac="true" validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" asyncTimeout="7" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never">
```

Is there a way for me reference a theme in the web.config without creating a virtual directory for my site?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you don't use SharePoint Theming engine in SP2013?

You could create your own custom theme and apply it on site using custom feature. I wrote a few blog posts on the topic few months back: http://blog.dragan-panjkov.com/archive/2012/09.aspx.

Let me know if this answers your question?

Comment: The theme that I have is really only setting styles for grids, so I wanted to avoid using the SharePoint theming engine.  Also, I'm just looking to get this done as quickly as possible, and learning how to get the theming engine to use my theme seems an inefficient use of my time right now.

Comment: Hm, Using SiteAssets is possible at SiteCollection level, but it can't be used on WebApplication level.